# Swift 3: how to check if cookies for particular URL are configured?

Tags: swift, cookies, authentication, nshttpcookie, nshttpcookiestorage

I'm building an app for an API with cookie-based validation, and am having several issues with it.

My current problem is a function to check if autologin cookie is configured for the domain, but I can't get my head around setting it up properly.

My current attempt is:

```
func cookiesConfigured() -> Bool {
    let cookieStorage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.dictionaryWithValues(forKeys: ["AutologinCookie"])
    if !cookieStorage.isEmpty {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
    return false // <- will never be executed
}
```

What would be the right way to check the cookie storage's contents for a particular cookie?

Comment: What did the HTTPCookieStorage documentation say?

Comment: I read the whole HTTPCookieStorage documentation twice and couldn't find a way to check if a particular cookie is set.

Comment: What's wrong with `cookies(for:)`?

Comment: Ok, I had a newb moment. I was too focused on the default `return false` not being executed, while already having both possibilities covered by the nil check. Thank you very much for guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you might have realized, `dictionaryWithValues` is an NSObject-method and doesn't do what you think it does.

What you need is to chain `cookiesFor`, `filter` and `isEmpty`.

Comment: That's exactly what happened. And your suggestion about `cookies(for:)` led me to a proper solution. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is Swift 3 code to get a particular cookie.

```
let cookieJar = HTTPCookieStorage.shared

for cookie in cookieJar.cookies! {

   if cookie.name == "MYNAME" {

      let cookieValue = cookie.value

      print("COOKIE VALUE = \(cookieValue)")
   }
}
```